# Shuffle parent DIV's with their respective children div's

Tags: jquery

I have a situation without solution.
In my website, I have a kind of gallery with business partners. I don't want they think the first ones are better than the last ones, so I have this code to shuffle the order of items each time the page is loaded.

The gallery structure follows this DIVS structure:

[image]

I'm using this script:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(function () {
      var parent = $('.ba-feature-grid-layout');
      var divs = parent.children();
      while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
      }
    });
});
```

It works, but jumbles all informations (children div's). The logo of a partner appears with the name of another and links to the websites are also confused. Any idea to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle a collection of elements.

- use `.find()` to get your child elements
- shuffle them
- .append() them back into $parent

```js
const fisherYatesShuffle = arr => {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
};

jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $('.ba-feature-grid-layout').each((i, el) => {
    const $this = $(el);
    const $boxes = $this.find(".ba-feature-box");
    const bosesShuffled = fisherYatesShuffle($boxes);
    $this.append(bosesShuffled);
  });

});
```

```css
.ba-feature-grid-layout { padding: 1rem;}
```

```html
<div class="ba-feature-grid-layout">
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Lorem</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Ipsum</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Dolor</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Sit</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Amet</div>
</div>

<div class="ba-feature-grid-layout">
  <div class="ba-feature-box">One</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Two</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Three</div>
  <div class="ba-feature-box">Four</div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Roko! It works, but the logo div does't sync with name/description/url div  block (logo of one partner is showing with another one). See my screenshot above to understandb better. I can't modify this structure because it's a plugin Balbooa Gridbox (Joomla).

Comment: @Vanderlei everything should work absolutely well since you're shuffling the parent wrappers. There's not other reason it should not work as expected.

Comment: unfortunately it's not with this structure:

<div class="ba-parent">
   <div class="ba-feature-box">
      <div class="ba-image" data-type="image">
         <div class="ba-feature-image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ba-caption">
         <div class="ba-title">
            <h3 class="ba-feature-title">NAME</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="ba-description">
            <div class="ba-feature-description">bla bla bla</div>
         </div>
         <div class="ba-feature-url"><a class="ba-url" target="_blank" href=""></a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: @Vanderlei yep it works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/9tzL08cq/ just changed the parent selector.